# Destroy an List Item element from the Drop down List sap ui5 IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, sapui5

I have a drop down box. It has the list populated using the list items and each list item is identified by id.
e.g.

```
oDropdownBox.addItem(new sap.ui.core.ListItem("curr_1",{text: currency_txt, key: currency_key}));
```

Similarly i have two more list items also.

But now my question is , i want to clear this list by destroying the items and add it with the same id.

I have the working code but it works only in Chrome.

```
if ( document.getElementById('curr_1') != null) sap.ui.getCore().byId("curr_1").destroy();
```

But the above code doesnt work in IE 8 ( Internet Explorer 8).

Could someone help me with the code.

I tried with lot of code

```
if ( document.getElementById("curr_1") != null) {
     var elem = document.getElementById("curr_1");
     elem.remove(elem.selectedIndex); 
}
```

and

```
if ( document.getElementById("curr_ch") != null) {
    var select = document.getElementById("curr_1");
    select.remove();
}
```

But none of them worked. Please help !!

Thanks
Sathish

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem?

Comment: No.. i changed my method of implementation.. i m using bind and unbind items property to add and remove from the list